# How to draw a filled pizza slice in html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fill

I want to draw a filled pizza slice in html5 canvas. I tried to use arc and to fill inside of it as it can be seen in the following code;

```
context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(node._private.position['x'],node._private.position['y'],node._private.style['width'].value + 10,
            0,2 * Math.PI/3-0.175, 0);
context.fill();
context.lineTo(node._private.position['x'],
node._private.position['y']);
context.arc(node._private.position['x'],node._private.position['y'],node._private.style['width'].value + 10,
            2 * Math.PI/3,4 * Math.PI/3-0.175, 0);
context.lineTo(node._private.position['x'],
node._private.position['y']);
context.arc(node._private.position['x'],node._private.position['y'],node._private.style['width'].value + 10,
            4 * Math.PI/3,2 * Math.PI-0.175, 0);
context.lineTo(node._private.position['x'],
node._private.position['y']);
context.lineTo(node._private.position['x'] + node._private.style['width'].value + 10,
node._private.position['y']);
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
```

However, it only fills like the following as expected;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyMFN.jpg

I want upper part of that arc (the triangle area) is to be filled, too. Should I add a filled triangle for that part or is there another way?

Comment: I solved it! I should have fill the arc after drawing the line to the node. Thank you very much.

Comment: When you found the answer yourself, [please answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so any future visitors can benefit from your experience.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it! I should have fill the arc after drawing the line to the node. Thank you very much